# what is Typescript Re-export?

Tags: typescript

I don't quite understand the meaning of re-export by reading the [official document](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import).

In a file called ParseIntBasedZipCodeValidator.ts

```
export class ParseIntBasedZipCodeValidator { 
    isAcceptable(s: string) {
        return s.length === 5 && parseInt(s).toString() === s;
    }
} // this part I understand

export {ZipCodeValidator as RegExpBasedZipCodeValidator} from "./ZipCodeValidator";
 // this part I don't understand
```

Here is the abstract of the problem:

```
export {A as B} from "./file1";
```

**Question:**
Please explain:

```
export {A as B} from "./file1";
```

**Question2:** 
Why do they call it re-export? Very confusing! I have the impression that re-export would replace the original imported object in its module.

Comment: Would it answer your question if I just said it's the equivalent of `import {A} from './file1'` followed by `export {A as B}`?

Comment: @E_net4 I can understand it perfectly:)

Comment: a file is a module. by default nothing is public. with export you can make things from your module/file public to other files. you can also re-export items imported from other files with a different name (in this case export A from file1 as B). This is useful to bundle things together or hide details of an implementation.

Comment: Now you just make it look like you have too many questions for a single SO question. Try rephrasing it a bit.

Comment: @toskv it is just export. Why do they call it re-export? Very confusing! I have the impression that re-export would replace the original imported object in its module.

Comment: It's a re-export because the other module had to export in the first place.

Comment: TBH I would include that last comment of yours in the actual question if I were you. :)

Comment: @E_net4 so in export {A as B} from "./file1"; means:
 A should be defined in "./file1" already,  I just import A from "file1", and then exported as B. Is this correct?

Comment: yes. people importing it from file2 (that being the file re-exporting it) would only see it as B.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

```
export {A as B} from "./file1";
```

This means import `A` from `./file1` and export it as `B`

**Question 2**
It's a reexport because it exports element which was already exported(by the source module)

Re-export are used quite often for bundling similar classes.

```
// EmailValidator.ts
class EmailValidator {
    isValid(email: string): boolean { ... }
}
```

---

```
// PhoneNumberValidator.ts
class PhoneNumberValidator {
    isValid(phoneNumber: string): boolean { ... }
}
```

---

```
// Validators.ts
export {EmailValidator} from "EmailValidator";
export {PhoneNumberValidator} from "PhoneNumberValidator";
```

Now you can import both validators from single file